# pnpm monorepo installed serval version of vite, it caused some typescript problem.it mismatching version of vite

Tags: typescript, vite, monorepo, pnpm

Here is my problem,
I have a monorepo which use pnpm，inside this monorepo i have **./packages/appsA** and **/packages/appsB** and **/packages/appsC**.

appsA installed vite@3.x， appsB installed vite@4.x.

inside appsB/vite.config.ts looks like this
[image: appsB/vite,config.ts]
the svgLoader goes wrong because it `import { Plugin } from 'vite'`, and when i click 'vite' it gose to version3.x not version4.x, and my `defineConfig`'s declaration is from version4.x, and that cause my promblem.
[image: svgLoader]
[image: serval version of vite]

how can i make this link right?